# How to access parent directive attributes inside the child directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have nested simple directives:

```
<ep:dropdown type="modern">
    <ep:dropdown:item color="red">Hello</ep:dropdown:item>
    <ep:dropdown:item color="blue">World</ep:dropdown:item>
</ep:dropdown>
```

Definition of `epDropdown` directive:

```
app.directive('epDropdown', function () {
    return {
        scope: {type: '@'},
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: function (elem, attr) {
            var template;

            if (attr.type == 'modern') {
                template = '<div ng-transclude></div>';
            }

            return template;
        },

        controller: function($scope) {
            this.type = $scope.type;
        }
    };
});
```

And `epDropdownItem` directive:

```
app.directive('epDropdownItem', function () {
    return {
        require: '^epDropdown',
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: { color: '@' },

        link: function (scope,element,attrs,parentCtrl){
            scope.type = parentCtrl.type;
        },

        template: function (elem, attr) {
            var template = '';
            console.log(attr.color); 
            console.log(attr.type); // undefined -> how to access `type` attr of parent
            return '<div>PARENT type: {{ type }} | CHILD color: {{ color }}</div>';
        },
    };
});
```

I can access the `type` attribute of parent directive inside the `template` string. **The problem is I can't access it inside the javascript itself. `console.log(attr.type)` returns `undefined`.** How can I access it? Here is **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D6598/1/)**.

Comment: Why do you want to access it. The value is already available on the scope, for you to bind? The attr is the attributes defined on this item not the parent

Comment: @Chandermani I want it to handle the `template` string dynamically. `if (attr.type == 'modern') { return templateA; } else { return templateB; }`.

Comment: I believe then you need to use the `elem` with jquery\jquery lite object and navigate to its parent and then check the attribute value using jquery itself

Comment: @Chandermani I want the `child` directive, generates different HTML based on `parent` directive attributes. There is no native way in angular? I think it shouldn't be so complex... However, I'll happy to see your suggestion way as an anwser (I don't know how to implement it).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the cleanest way of solving the given problem, but it works. You can navigate to the parent element via jqLite and access the attributes:

```
elem.parent().attr("type");
```

Updated & working: http://jsfiddle.net/D6598/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you do a console.log of **elem** in child, it returns the child element which does not have type property.

But when the child is transcluded in the parent element, which has a **type** property it get that property value.